# Не выбирается нужный уровень сложности в игре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу викторину на Python 3.7. Код выглядит так:

```
def x():
    y = input('T')
    if y=="easy" or "Easy":
        направо пойдёшь
    elif y=="medium" or "Medium":
        налево пойдёшь
    elif y=="hard" or "Hard":
        прямо пойдёшь
    else:
        print("O")
    x()
```

Проблема собственно в том, что в любом случае выбирается лёгкий уровень сложности, то бишь текст про Лондон. Где ошибка?

Comment: Тогда уж, lvl_name и название сложности приводить к одному регистру, например к нижнему: `y = input('T').lower()` и сравнивать только с одним вариантом -- `if y=="easy":`. А то если напишу "EASY", то ваш код до `else` дойдет хотя по задумке так не должно быть :)

Comment: Синтаксис языка состоит в том, что `or` разделяет логические выражения, а врыжение вида `lvl == 'level'` как раз логическое и, если в строке записано `'level'`, то и вернет соответственно `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании опретора or нужно после него снова сравнить переменную:
if a == 1 or a == 2:
Функция welcome:

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the game! Select a level of difficulty! Be careful: you have only 5 attempts for one question.")
    lvl_name = input('Type in easy, medium or hard. ')
    if lvl_name=="easy" or lvl_name=="Easy":
        main(easy_lvl, numbers, easy_lvl_answers)
    elif lvl_name=="medium" or lvl_name=="Medium":
        main(medium_lvl, numbers, medium_lvl_answers)
    elif lvl_name=="hard" or lvl_name=="Hard":
        main(hard_lvl, numbers, hard_lvl_answers)
    else:
        print("You are a tricky one! Well, now tell me please: easy, medium or hard?")
    welcome()
```

Comment: Вы бы объяснили почему. Человеку ведь непонятно, как строка в булевое значение превратилась

Comment: Вместо `if lvl_name=="easy" or lvl_name=="Easy"` лучше эквивалентное `if lvl_name in ("easy", "Easy")`. Но еще лучше перевести результат input() в нижний регистр и проверять только один вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = input('T')
d = dict(easy='направо пойдёшь', medium='налево пойдёшь', hard='прямо пойдёшь')
print(d.get(y.lower(), "O"))
```